# ...fetch() and toJSON() response is not matching

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

I am making a service call using collection url. The service returns some json, the json length is 13 (in short 13 rows of data).

Here, this.Collection.fetch() is returning json who's length is 13.
but this.Collection.toJSON() is returning json who's length is 12.
instead it should return length 13.

In collection parse, the response is returning json who's length is 13, which is correct!

tableTemplate is object of template (template is done using Handlebars.js).

this.Collection.fetch({
        success: function(){

```
        console.log("Collection Fetch 2:");
        console.log(this.Collection.fetch());

        console.log("Collection toJSON: ");
        console.log(this.Collection.toJSON());
        console.log(this.Collection.toJSON().length);


        var markup = tableTemplate({List:self.importCollection.toJSON()});
         ...
          ...
    }
});
```

Comment: some more context would help

Comment: It's unclear what you'd be expecting to work when calling `fetch` inside of the callback for `fetch` for the same collection. The second `fetch` also would be async.

Comment: Can you please review it again and explain me whats going on in my code.

Comment: can you show the output of console.log here.

Comment: Are there columns with the same name? From what you've observed, what column is being removed when `toJSON()` is called?

Comment: Actually, 1 complete rows is not displayed.

I think there are 2 rows with same id, Is this be an Issues
But i have not used any rendering logic in template.
what data is coming from JSON, It will be directly passed to handlebars template and the rows are displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats the asynchronous nature of javascript/backbone

do it like this :

```
this.collection.fetch();

//Fetch() is asynchronous call , when it completes fetching it triggers the **reset**   event so you need a event listener for **reset**

this.collection.on('reset',function(data){
console.log(data);                          // this will log the object
});

this.collection.on('reset',function(data){
console.log(JSON.stringify(data));        // This will log the JSON data  
});
```

OR you could do this :

```
this.collection.fetch({
success : function(){                      // called on completion of fetch()
console.log(data);       
console.log(JSON.stringify(data));  
}
});
```

Comment: Yes, but in "data" response is having 12 models, instead there should be 13 models !

Comment: what does this.collection.length give you ?

Comment: It is giving me 12, instead it should be 13.

Comment: My parse is returning correct json response who's length is 13.
But, my this.collection.fetch is returning wrong length i.e. 12.